# Why do we get time-stamp issue in progress database?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

> we have upgrade from 9.1 to 11.3 version.it was working fine for two days and later database went down.In the log file its mentioned .lk fie is deleted.we are getting the below error
>   When we do
>
> proutil qhn -C truncate BI
>
> OpenEdge Release 11.3 as of Wed Jul 17 16:45:17 EDT 2013
>
> ** The database was last used Mon Oct 13 12:15:15 2014. (886)
>   ** The before-image file expected Tue Oct 14 12:48:47 2014. (887)
>   ** Those dates don't match, so you have the wrong copy of one of them. (888)
>
> We have restored the db from backup.We need to know the Root cause analysis for the below issue for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deleted the .lk file and probably used OS tools to manipulate one or more files that make up the db (that includes the bi file).

This is common in "cowboy" shops where admins do things like delete the .lk file or use "kill -9" on users.

The root cause is simple - someone used something other than Progress to manipulate the database.  That is exactly what the error message means and you do not get this error for any other reason.

You can do this to yourself easily.  "Touch" any of the db extents or the bi file.  Or copy them somewhere and copy them back (the "mv" command does not usually impact timestamps so that is ok).

Comment: so it happens only because of .lk file deletion?

Comment: No.  That's just a red flag that suggests a probable pattern of sys admin malfeasance.

Comment: The root cause is simple - someone used something other than Progress to manipulate the database.